# zeros of orthogonal polynomial satisfying $f_n (x) = (x-2n^2) f_{n-1}(x)- n^2 (n-1)^2 f_{n-2}(x)$

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

I am trying solving Romania TST 2014 problem #3 of day 3
http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3717806&sid=523a7da94c84b9ea1123a6b2f6302d34#p3717806

After finding out the gradient of both sides to apply Lagrange's multiplier method, it turns into a eigenvalue problem of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix whose $n^{th}$ diagonal is $2n^2$ and whose $(i,i+1)-th$ elements $-ij$ which is also the $(i+1,i)-th$ element and $0$ anywhere other than the diagonal, superdiagonal, subdiagonal.

That matrix's characterstic equation is in turn the orthogonal polynomials satisfying

$f_n (x) = (x-2n^2) f_{n-1}(x)- n^2 (n-1)^2 f_{n-2}(x)$

with $ f_1 (x) = x-2 , f_2 (x) = x^2 - 10x +12 $

I know that those orthogonal polynomials have $n$ distinct real zeros, which can be verified through two different ways 1. eigenvalues of real symmetric matrix 2. Sturm-Liouvile Theory.

But I have no ideas how to proceed from here. I know that In the case of Chebyshef or other famous special polynomials there are explicit formulas for the roots of those polynomials, but is there any hint where I can get a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do "from here"?   $f_n$ has Galois group $S_n$ for $n=4$ to $9$, so you won't get explicit expressions in terms of radicals for the roots for $n = 5$ to $9$.